# Convert Numbers to Letter

Tags: r, type-conversion

I'm trying to write a code where I find the alphabetical character for number. something like the reverse version of the Letters function

```
numbers(0:26)
```

then

```
5
```

returns

```
e
```

or and 10 returns j etc

Comment: `letters[5]` returns `e`. What else you want?

Comment: `letters` isn't a function, it's a built-in constant like `pi`, which is why you subset it with `[...]` instead of call it with `(...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`letters` is a reserved word in R.

```
letters
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w"
[24] "x" "y" "z"
```

So type `letters[5]`, you will get `e`. Type `letters[10]`, you will get `j`.

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful. It seems like a silly question now but I'm sure i was getting an error earlier with this approach, clearly I was doing something wrong